# Angular 4: How to access element inside ng-template

Tags: angular

I have a view which holds ng template for MD-Dialog.

```
<ng-template #template>
  <h2 md-dialog-title>{{title}}</h2>
  <div md-dialog-content #content></div>
</ng-template>
```

Where I have to replace #content with a dynamic component.

corresponding component class is,

```
export class CustomDialogComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  title: string;

  @ViewChild('content', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;

  @ViewChild('template') template: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  open(component: any, options: any): void {

    this.title = options.title;
    console.log(this.container)
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.template, options);
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    this.container.clear();
    const comp = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
    comp.instance.setData(options.data);

  }

  close() {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.container)
  }
}
```

But I get undefined for this.container in method open(). Please help.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo?

Comment: demo is little difficult at the moment. let me shorten the problem, i want to access  #content in the method open(). since it is in ng-template, im not able to access it.

Comment: so create a minimal demo

Comment: https://angular-ukdpqg.stackblitz.io here is the demo and code is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukdpqg

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `@ViewChild('content')` will be available only after creation embedded view

Answer (score 4):

template inside a template is reachable only when view is initialized, so
after angular 8, when using ViewChild, you can use parameter`{static: false}`
this way you can have instance of the inside template when view is initialized

```
@Viewchild('content', {static: false}) innerConttent: TemplateRef<any>;
```